# Can I change email content without stopping a journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder, content-builder

I've created a journey in salesforce marketing cloud to send a set of emails. This journey is currently active & running.

I want to do some changes in existing content of one of the email (for example I want to change url of CTA button).

1. If I go to content builder & change content of that email. Will it reflect in ongoing journey?
   or
2. I need to stop existing journey and create a new version with updated email content.

Which one will work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to stop the journey in that case. Each email activity in Journey Builder creates a triggered email interaction in the background, that you can publish the changes to.

There are two ways to do this:

**Option 1** (Source: [SFMC Documentation: Update an Email in a Running Journey](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_update_an_email_in_a_running_journey.htm&type=5)):

1. In the running journey - hover over the email activity.
2. Click **"View or Update Activity"**
3. Click through to the last step of the activity and click **"Done"**.
4. Exit the activity.

**Option 2:**

1. Navigate to *Email Studio > Interactions > Triggered Emails > Journey Builder Sends > [Your Journey] > Version [Your Journey Version]*. There you will find all email activities of your journey.
2. Check the boxes next to the emails you like to update and click the **"Pause"** button, which will temporarily pause the email sends (no sends will be lost, all sends in the meantime will be queued).
3. As soon as the activities have been paused, check the boxes again and click **"Publish Changes"**.
4. After you see the success-message, again check the boxes and click **"Start/Restart"**.

Comment: Option 2 is no longer available: "All triggered send edits can be made directly inside the Journey Builder Send Email activity. Pausing triggered sends here does not pause a contact's progression through the Journey. Learn more." http://help.marketingcloud.com/send_email_activity

Comment: Option 2 is in fact available, I used it today. This is the way to go if you like to bulk update many emails in one journey as you don't have to click through the wizards of all emails. And that the progression in the journey isn't paused for the contact was a requirement of the original poster.

Comment: sooo, i took your option 2, @MarkusDang-formerlySlabina, and added a method to mcdev that does that for all active triggeredsends on a given BU (or selectively by key). Will be released with mcdev 4.3 https://github.com/Accenture/sfmc-devtools/pull/643

Answer (score 3):

Another approach, in addition to the one suggested by Markus, which I use in connection with Journeys and Triggered Sends, is extended use of [Reference Block](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ceb_add_a_reference_block.htm&type=5) instead of having the code within the body of the email itself. In this way, the emails you send out will always be up to date, as the content will be fetched from the external content block at send time, without the need for updating the activity in Journey Builder.

Comment: When designing new emails this is definitely the way to go and I also do it that way in most cases, however it doesn't solve the problem if you already are using emails without reference content in the journey.

Comment: Reference blocks worked for me in the past but not anymore. Today when I tried to change a header for email banner by another image URL. The journey still sent the email with the old header to me while the header section is a reference content.